# Simulate GPS location on iPhone without Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, location, core-location

For a little project I´m trying to simulate locations on my iPhone/iPad with the existing Maps - App. With XCode on Mac, you can simulate locations with the help of a GPX-file. But is this also possible without Xcode? Can the GPX-file be saved on the iPhone and then started from there? A second option would be to create a new map using MapKit. But I actually want to use the internal Maps app.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Look for "idevicesetlocation" https://libimobiledevice.org https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/blob/25059d4c7d75e03aab516af2929d7c6e6d4c17de/tools/idevicesetlocation.c

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunatelly this is not possible. There is no way how you can save GPX-file at real device without Xcode simulator at this point.